# breeze/durandal: configureBreezeManager().saveChanges() doesn't trigger function subscribed hasChangesChanged

Tags: javascript, breeze, durandal, hottowel

I'm been creating a web site following Hottowl's example. However, the value of `hasChanges` is not changed after `saveChanges` is called - even the data is actually saved in database table. I use hottowel durandal 2.0.1. I found the durandal version is different from the CCJS-Scratch example. Did I miss anything?

datacontext.js

```
    var manager = configureBreezeManager();
    var hasChanges = ko.observable(false);

    manager.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(function (eventArgs) {
        hasChanges(eventArgs.hasChanges); // The function isn't called when saveChanges is called
    });

    var cancelChanges = function () {
        manager.rejectChanges();
        log('Canceled changes', null, true);
    };

    var saveChanges = function () {
        return manager.saveChanges()
            .then(saveSucceeded)
            .fail(saveFailed);

        function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
            log('Saved data successfully', saveResult, true);
        }

        function saveFailed(error) {
            var msg = 'Save failed: ' + getErrorMessages(error);
            logError(msg, error);
            error.message = msg;
            throw error;
        }
    };
```

The following code exist in the view model.

```
    var hasChanges = ko.computed(function () {
        return datacontext.hasChanges();
    });

    var cancel = function () {
        datacontext.cancelChanges();
    };

    var canSave = ko.computed(function () {
        return hasChanges() && !isSaving();
    });

    var save = function () {
        isSaving(true);
        return datacontext.saveChanges().fin(complete);

        function complete() {
            isSaving(false);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a timing issue? You have a lot of nested observables and computed observables that I have trouble aligning at this late hour.

What I do know is that the Breeze *DocCode:saveTodoTests.js* show that `hasChangesChanged` is called with the correct `eventArgs.hasChanges` value when both saving changes and reverting (`rejectChanges`). Here is a passing test from that suite that confirms it.

```
test("hasChangesChanged event raised after saveChanges", 4, function () {
    var em = newTodosEm();    
    var hasChangesChangedRaised = [];
    em.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(
        function(eventArgs) {
            hasChangesChangedRaised.push(eventArgs.hasChanges);
        }
    );

    // add a Todo (and forget about it)
    em.createEntity('TodoItem',{ Description: "Learn to save in breeze" });

    stop();
    em.saveChanges()
       .then ( function() {
           equal(hasChangesChangedRaised.length, 2,
            "hasChangesChanged should have been raised twice");
           ok(hasChangesChangedRaised[0]===true,
            "first hasChangesChanged is true after create");
           ok(hasChangesChangedRaised[1]===false,
            "second hasChangesChanged is false after save");
           ok(!em.hasChanges(),
            "manager should not have pending changes after save");
        })
       .fail(handleSaveFailed)
       .fin(start);
});
```

Note that the `hasChangesChanged` event is raised twice in this test.

Please try debugging again and make sure that the event you're looking at is the one raised *after* the save, not during some other manipulation.

Also watch out for the nesting of KO events. Race conditions are possible.

Comment: The code is almost exactly the same as the one in Johny Papa's HotTowel CCJS-Scratch example. The `manager.rejectChanges();` will trigger the function though.

Comment: Your challenge is to prove it. I've offered DocCode proof that the function works as expected. I just debugged my way through my copy of the HotTowel CCJS-Scratch sample (admittedly old at v.1.4.1) and it behaves as expected. The ball is in your court to provide a ***small*** sample that fails.